# Redirect to social media pages from react-native app

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, instagram, instagram-api

In react-native app I want to redirect to social media pages (instagram/facebook/twitter) of company. I tried react-native linking but it didn't work and also react-native-instagram-login it opens instagram login page instead of redirecting to application.